# Duplicate profiles showing up in SharePoint 2010 search results

Tags: search, user-profile, user-profile-service, fast-search

Ok, this one is a bit odd.  In my environment we have FAST Search Server 2010, everything is configured and working properly.

Recently we had to run a full profile sync in the User Profile Service Application to resolve some discrepancies.  Since then, when doing a People Search on a FAST Search Center, many people are returning multiple results.  What makes it very odd is that one result goes to their NT Login and the other to a GUID.

For example:

http://{SITE}/my/Person.aspx?guid=6DC4DB25-03C0-4790-9DD8-C7DBF73603F6

and

http://{SITE}/my/Person.aspx?accountname=DOMAIN\user

The one referencing the NT login works as expected.  However, when selecting the GUID result, it gives a User Not Found error message.

I had reset the search index on the FAST Query SSA (where the people search results come from) and recrawled.  The issue still exists.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: John, Have you looked at the UPS Profile Manager (Manage User Profiles) and viewed the profile(s) for a particular account?  You should be able to look up the user by name or username and see if there are two entries.

Comment: There aren't any duplicates in the User Profile Service Application.  Searched for one of the users in question.  Also, the number of profiles listed (2,419) hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what is causing those other profiles to show up, however I was able to work around the issue by adding the following Crawl Rule to exclude:

> http://{SITE}/my/Person.aspx*guid=*

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues recently after I tried to reset my FAST Index and found that it didn't actually reset the index.  Try resetting it again and see if there are any people results returned before doing a full crawl.

Comment: Resetting the index in Central Admin on the FAST Query SSA will remove people from search. Resetting the index on the FAST Content SSA will remove the crawler database entries for any content, not the items itself (which must be cleared on FAST via PowerShell). And People search has nothing to do with FAST per say.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had 2 enteries in the crawl for sps3 content.  I set the crawl to only use one of the sites and had good data after a full crawl.